# SQL Like statement is ordering results

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008-r2

Can somebody please explain why a simple SQL LIKE statement will cause results to be ordered by the column that is being 'liked'...

```
select * from ORGANISATION where COMPANY_NAME LIKE '%marce%'
```

the above will cause the results to be ordered by company name...

```
select * from ORGANISATION
```

will show results in index / id order.

Comment: It won't. There's probably an index on that column. The order is not guaranteed unless you specify an `ORDER BY`.

Comment: Indeed and +1 to the above. Your table is an unordered relation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ORDER` is not guaranteed without explicitly using an `ORDER BY` clause.  It's arbitrary. There could exist an index on the field, which is usually responsible for the 'natural' ordering of results, but shouldn't be relied upon.

Comment: I've checked and your right, there is an index on it, when doing a like on a non indexed column it has no ordering kind of effect.

Comment: This was kind of a side issue as im working in L2E and checking if a query is ordered and if not applying an order by the first parameter (because of the SKIP bug), so the apparent ordering of a statement which has no explicit ordering was baffling me a bit. Thanks.